# Rails - Can I use observer to cancel the save of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, observer-pattern

I have a `before_save` observer in one of my models, can I cancel the saving process if a certain condition is matched in the observer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. Just return `false` from your observer. It will cancel the save.

At least if you use Rails 3.1 that is. If you use an older version of Rails, you have to define a callback method using:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :my_callback

  def my_callback
    # do something
    false
  end
end
```